# Powerbuilder ImportFile / SaveAs

Tags: powerbuilder

My client requires to Import Text Files into the system but their Textfiles are Pipe Delimited "|". Also they require to Export some of data into the same format (Pipe delimited). I was asked to use Powerbuilder 12. Is it possible to ImportFile with PipeDelimited Textfiles directly? I would like to skip the "FOR LOOP MID GET" Method and go directly for importfile then update(). Same goes for the dw.saveas().

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know we are not lucky with the import, because we could not define the separator, but here is a little workaround:

1. Read the file into a string variable
2. Replace the pipes | to commas ,
3. Import the string as a CSV into the dw

I made a little test app for you and it worked. My text files is like this:

Col1|Col2|Col3

aaa|bbb|ccc

Here is the import code:

```
string  ls_import, ls_export
long    ll_filehandle, ll_readbytes
// IMPORT
ll_filehandle = FileOpen("d:\Work\StackExchange\pipes.txt", TextMode!)   
ll_readbytes    = FileReadEx(ll_filehandle, ls_import)

if ll_filehandle = -1 or IsNull(ll_filehandle) then
else
    ls_import   = f_glo_replace_all(ls_import, "|", ",")
    dw_1.ImportString(CSV!, ls_import)
end if
```

With the export we have more luck. There is a datawindow method in which you can customize the separator for the export:

[SaveAsFormattedText](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc37783_1150/html/dwref/BABIHIDF.htm)

So the import would look like this:

dw_1.SaveAsFormattedText("d:\Work\StackExchange\export_pipes.txt", EncodingANSI!, "|")

Of course you will need the code of the global replace function:

Here is the source:

```
global type f_glo_replace_all from function_object
end type

forward prototypes
global function string f_glo_replace_all (string source, string look_for, string replace_with)
end prototypes

global function string f_glo_replace_all (string source, string look_for, string replace_with);/*A String Occurrence Search and Replace RoutineThe following code demonstrates a string occurrence search and replaceroutine.This routine works generically for any string. For example,if old_str = "red" and new_str ="green", all occurrences of "red" inside of mystring will be replaced with "green". 
Parameters 
Name = source Type = String 
Name = look_for Type = String 
Name = replace_with Type = String 
*/ 
int start_pos=1,len_look_for 

len_look_for = len(lower(look_for)) 
//find the first occurrence of look_for ... 
start_pos = Pos(lower(source),lower(look_for), start_pos) 
//only enter the loop if you find whats in look_for 
DO WHILE start_pos > 0 
    //replace look_for with replace_with ... 
    source = Replace(source,start_pos,Len_look_for,replace_with) 
    //find the next occurrence of 
    start_pos = Pos(lower(source), lower(look_for), start_pos+Len(replace_with)) 
LOOP 
return source 
end function
```

I hope this helps!

Br. Gábor

Comment: I think this is the same as "FOR LOOP MID GET" as it needs to read line by line, for detail items less than 10 it would be practical but I am faced to about 1000 lines daily per file. Sadly I think I dont have any choice.

Comment: For the import yes it's like that, except the file is read at once, and only changing the pipes is similar to that "read per line" method BUT for the export there is a fine solution!

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible the way you want.  You'll need to write your own version of the ImportFile, sorry it is not the answer you wanted.